# Help with statistical TSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have few tables that gather data for internal use but i want to write all data to other table from which i can easily query statistical data without joins, group by and other mess. This select insert query will be run as maintenance plan each 10 minutes.

I have 3 tables with data

```
Visitors (id int, siteID int, date smalldatetime, isRead bit, isActive bit)
VisitorLastLocation (id int, visitorID int, siteID int, durationInSeconds int)
VisitorLocations(visitorLastLocationID int)
```

new item is added to Visitors table each time unique visitor comes to certain site, same goes for VisitorLastLocation. Next visit of already existing Visitor adds previous location to VisitorLocations and updates VisitorLastLocation table.

I need to fill this table each 10 minutes.

```
VisitorStatistics(id int, siteID int, visits int, pageViews int, isReadNumber int, isActiveNumber int, durationSum int, date smalldatetime)
```

So if you get me right i need to group by each selection by raw date (ie. 2/2/11 13:30 and not 2/2/11 13:31) and by siteID.

How would you advice to solve this, full solution will be very helpful...

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?   You get more help if you don't just say "Here is what I need plz send teh codez"

Comment: The only thing i've done was to create update for each column as the time by first creating empty date calendar which joined with with query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, all you are missing is the code to round a DATETIME to the lower 30 minute interval.  DATEDIFF and DATEADD should help you here...

```
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [date]) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [date]) % 30), 0),
  siteID
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that all in one query? I mean to update all fields i need?

Comment: I gather, your *30* minutes are the OP's *10* minutes. In any event, `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [date]) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [date]) % 30)` can be simplified to `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [date]) / 30 * 30`.

Comment: The benefit of `X - (X % 30)` is that X is calculated once and reused.  This means that it involves `DATEDIFF`, `-` and `%`.  Where as the shorter alternative involves `DATEDIFF`, `/` AND `%`.  And `/` is a much more costly operation than `-`.  Admittedly, though, this will be marginal; it's a hang-over from my C++ coding.